# ReCaptcha For Newbies

Tags: recaptcha

I've got ReCaptcha working but despite reading the documentation and the answers posted here, I'm still at a loss for setting up the server side.  My HTML form calls `<form id="contactForm" class="well" method="POST" action="php/contactform.php">`.

What and where do I place the server-side recaptcha in this file?  (I meant it when I titled this newbie.  I really need explicit instructions):

```
<?php
if($_POST){
// response hash
$response = array('message'=>''); 
}

try {       
    // Get values from form 
    $name=$_POST['cname'];
    $email=$_POST['cemail'];
    $subject=$_POST['csubject'];
    $message=$_POST['cmessage'];


    $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Subject: $subject \n: $message";
    $recipient = "rabbidubrow@fivegates.org";
    $subject = "KHF Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    $send_contact=mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");   

    // let's assume everything is ok, setup successful response
        $response['type'] = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Thank you! We will be in touch shortly.';   
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $response['type'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    // now we are ready to turn this hash into JSON
    print json_encode($response);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need 
 1. Include your recaptcha.php
 2. Declare your private and public keys
 3. Check for POST of your captcha. If it success, give a response, if it fails, catch the exception.

Below is one of my scripts that was done up for your reference.

```
require_once('assets/config/recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "xxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxx";


if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if ($resp->is_valid) {
            $continue = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this?  At the top of my contactform.php file?  And what do I put in for REMOTE_ADDR?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start

This will help. I am still using text captcha as i like it that way. The version 2.0 will be easier to understand.

Comment: I looked at that.  Several times.  But I just couldn't understand the details.  So the above code is more helpful for me.  I just need those two questions answered.

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR will just be that. The array will be filled by itself. This will be placed in the php of wherever you are POST-ing the form to. For my case, I post-ed to register.php, hence I placed it in register.php

Comment: OK.  I think I've got it.  Where do I get recaptchalib.php ?I checked the reCaptcha website but didn't see it.

Comment: Got the library.  But I'm still able to submit the form without checking the Robot box.

Comment: You will need to add this
`if (!$continue) {
  //your error code or stop the thing etc
}`

Comment: I have this from yours:  if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
         $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
         if ($resp->is_valid) {
             $continue = true;
         }
 }
And I have this for an error with the form: } catch(Exception $e){
   $response['type'] = 'error';
   $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
  }                                Where do I add your code?  P.S. I really, really, appreciate your walking me through this.